# powershell: how to print command to file?

Tags: powershell, scripting, shell-scripting, powershell-v4.0

I'm currently using the Out-File cmdlet, like so:

```
PS> Some-Cmdlet -someswitch | Out-File -filepath .\somefile.txt
```

It works great.

Is there anyway that I can actually get the command line *itself* to print to the same file *before* the output?

In other words, when I open `somefile.txt` I want to see the following:

```
Some-Cmdlet -someswitch | Out-File -filepath .\somefile.txt

OUTPUT
OUTPUT
OUTPUT
etc.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `start-transcript`:

> The Start-Transcript cmdlet creates a record of all or part of a Windows PowerShell session in a text file. The transcript includes all command that the user types and all output that appears on the console.

So you'd want to do:

```
start-transcript -path c:\temp\transcript.txt -noclobber

... do sume stuff ...

stop-transcript
```